# Triangle button android click / hovered

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have created a triangular button in android. It works well.
I just want to change the fill color / stroke color when the button is hovered / pressed (like in the default button).

I try to invalidate the view when the hovered property changed and change the color in the OnDraw method without success.

This is my code:

```
public enum TriangularButtonDirection
{
    Up = 0,
    Down = 1
}

class TriangularButton : Button
{
    public TriangularButton(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        this.Initialize(null);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.Initialize(null);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    private TriangularButtonDirection _direction = TriangularButtonDirection.Down;

    private void Initialize(IAttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        if (attributeSet != null)
        {
            TypedArray a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, Resource.Styleable.TriangularButton);

            int direction = a.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.TriangularButton_direction, -1);
            if (direction > -1)
                this._direction = (TriangularButtonDirection)direction;
            a.Recycle();
        }
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.GetX();
        float y = e.GetY();
        int width = this.MeasuredWidth;
        PointF point1Draw;
        PointF point2Draw;
        PointF point3Draw;
        if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
        }
        bool test = PointInTriangle(new PointF(x, y), point1Draw, point2Draw, point3Draw);
        if (test)
            base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        return (test);
    }

    public static bool PointInTriangle(PointF p, PointF p0, PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        float s = p0.Y * p2.X - p0.X * p2.Y + (p2.Y - p0.Y) * p.X + (p0.X - p2.X) * p.Y;
        float t = p0.X * p1.Y - p0.Y * p1.X + (p0.Y - p1.Y) * p.X + (p1.X - p0.X) * p.Y;
        if ((s < 0) != (t < 0))
            return false;
        float a = -p1.Y * p2.X + p0.Y * (p2.X - p1.X) + p0.X * (p1.Y - p2.Y) + p1.X * p2.Y;
        if (a < 0.0)
        {
            s = -s;
            t = -t;
            a = -a;
        }
        return s > 0 && t > 0 && (s + t) <= a;
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        this.SetMeasuredDimension(this.MeasuredWidth, 3 * this.MeasuredWidth / 4);
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int width = this.MeasuredWidth;

        Paint paintFill = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        paintFill.StrokeWidth = 2; 
        paintFill.Color = this.Hovered ? Color.Red : new Color(242, 180, 54);
        paintFill.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
        paintFill.AntiAlias = true;

        Paint paintStroke = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        paintStroke.StrokeWidth = 2;
        paintStroke.Color = Color.White;
        paintStroke.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Stroke);
        paintStroke.AntiAlias = true;

        PointF point1Draw;
        PointF point2Draw;
        PointF point3Draw;
        if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.SetFillType(Path.FillType.EvenOdd);
        path.MoveTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point2Draw.X, point2Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point3Draw.X, point3Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
        path.Close();

        canvas.DrawPath(path, paintFill);
        canvas.DrawPath(path, paintStroke);
    }
}
```

EDIT : final code

```
    class TriangularButton : Button
{
    public TriangularButton(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
        this.Initialize(null);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        this.Initialize(null);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) : base(context, attrs)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    public TriangularButton(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        this.Initialize(attrs);
    }

    private TriangularButtonDirection _direction = TriangularButtonDirection.Down;
    private TriangularButtonState _state = TriangularButtonState.Normal;
    private Paint _paintFillNormal;
    private Paint _paintStrokeNormal;
    private Paint _paintFillPressed;
    private Paint _paintStrokePressed;
    private void Initialize(IAttributeSet attributeSet)
    {
        if (attributeSet != null)
        {
            TypedArray a = this.Context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, Resource.Styleable.TriangularButton);

            int direction = a.GetInt(Resource.Styleable.TriangularButton_direction, -1);
            if (direction > -1)
                this._direction = (TriangularButtonDirection)direction;
            a.Recycle();
        }

        this._paintFillNormal = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        this._paintFillNormal.StrokeWidth = 2;
        this._paintFillNormal.Color = new Color(242, 180, 54);
        this._paintFillNormal.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
        this._paintFillNormal.AntiAlias = true;

        this._paintFillPressed = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        this._paintFillPressed.StrokeWidth = 2;
        this._paintFillPressed.Color = new Color(255, 255, 255, 51);
        this._paintFillPressed.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
        this._paintFillPressed.AntiAlias = true;


        this._paintStrokeNormal = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        this._paintStrokeNormal.StrokeWidth = 2;
        this._paintStrokeNormal.Color = Color.White;
        this._paintStrokeNormal.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Stroke);
        this._paintStrokeNormal.AntiAlias = true;

        this._paintStrokePressed = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        this._paintStrokePressed.StrokeWidth = 2;
        this._paintStrokePressed.Color = new Color(51, 51, 51, 51);
        this._paintStrokePressed.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Stroke);
        this._paintStrokePressed.AntiAlias = true;



    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get => this._isEnabled;
        set
        {
            if (this._isEnabled != value)
            {
                this._isEnabled = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (!this._isEnabled)
            return (false);
        float x = e.GetX();
        float y = e.GetY();
        int width = this.MeasuredWidth;
        PointF point1Draw;
        PointF point2Draw;
        PointF point3Draw;
        if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
        }
        bool test = PointInTriangle(new PointF(x, y), point1Draw, point2Draw, point3Draw);
        if (test)
        {
            base.OnTouchEvent(e);
        }
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                this._state = TriangularButtonState.Pressed;
                test = true;
                this.Invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.HoverEnter:
                this._state = TriangularButtonState.Hovered;
                this.Invalidate();
                break;

            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                this._state = TriangularButtonState.Normal;
                this.Invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.HoverExit:
                this._state = TriangularButtonState.Normal;
                this.Invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return (test);
    }

    public static bool PointInTriangle(PointF p, PointF p0, PointF p1, PointF p2)
    {
        float s = p0.Y * p2.X - p0.X * p2.Y + (p2.Y - p0.Y) * p.X + (p0.X - p2.X) * p.Y;
        float t = p0.X * p1.Y - p0.Y * p1.X + (p0.Y - p1.Y) * p.X + (p1.X - p0.X) * p.Y;
        if ((s < 0) != (t < 0))
            return false;
        float a = -p1.Y * p2.X + p0.Y * (p2.X - p1.X) + p0.X * (p1.Y - p2.Y) + p1.X * p2.Y;
        if (a < 0.0)
        {
            s = -s;
            t = -t;
            a = -a;
        }
        return s > 0 && t > 0 && (s + t) <= a;
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        this.SetMeasuredDimension(this.MeasuredWidth, 3 * this.MeasuredWidth / 4);
    }

    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        int width = this.MeasuredWidth;

        PointF point1Draw;
        PointF point2Draw;
        PointF point3Draw;
        if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
            point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
            point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
        }

        Path path = new Path();
        path.SetFillType(Path.FillType.EvenOdd);
        path.MoveTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point2Draw.X, point2Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point3Draw.X, point3Draw.Y);
        path.LineTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
        path.Close();
        if (!this.Enabled)
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(path, this._paintStrokeNormal);
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.DrawPath(path, this._state == TriangularButtonState.Normal ? this._paintFillNormal : this._paintFillPressed);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, this._state == TriangularButtonState.Normal ? this._paintStrokeNormal : this._paintStrokePressed);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't understand, is this a Xamarin.Android project? Why you want to create a subclass of `Button`? Usually we customize a `Button` directly in xml.

Comment: Yes, I use Xamarin.Android. I can customize the button but I can't have the desired result.
Triangle with border are not possible with style file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes, I use Xamarin.Android. I can customize the button but I can't have the desired result. Triangle with border are not possible with style file...

Just from your code, I think your "Triangle with border" means a triangle button stroke, then you can create it with drawable resource file, for example, create three drawable for normal, pressed and hovered state:

Normal(The code for triangle shape comes from [this blog](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%">
      <shape
          android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#800000" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#ee9ca8" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

The code for "pressed" and "focused" state are the same, I just changed the color  of stroke and solid.

Then you can apply this drawable with selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/triangleClick" />
  <!-- pressed -->
  <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/triangleHover" />
  <!-- focused -->
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/triangleNormal" />
  <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Finally use this selector like this:

```
<Button android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/triangleSelector"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
```

Checked the result of my demo (state order is: normal->pressed->hovered):

[image]

Update:

You can get the three sides stroked like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%">
      <shape
          android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#800000" android:width="5dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="#ee9ca8" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
  <item android:top="65dp" android:right="5dp" android:left="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="#800000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can calculate the margin to make it more beautiful, it's just a idea to add another item to this layer.

Update 2:

Besides the method I wrote in comments, to continue your work for doing this in custom button class, you can code for example like this:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    float x = e.GetX();
    float y = e.GetY();
    int width = this.MeasuredWidth;
    PointF point1Draw;
    PointF point2Draw;
    PointF point3Draw;
    if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
    {
        point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
        point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
        point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
        point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
        point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
    }

    bool test = PointInTriangle(new PointF(x, y), point1Draw, point2Draw, point3Draw);
    if (test)
        base.OnTouchEvent(e);

    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            mstate = state.pressed;
            this.Invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.HoverEnter:
            mstate = state.hovered;
            this.Invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            mstate = state.normal;
            this.Invalidate();
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.HoverExit:
            mstate = state.normal;
            this.Invalidate();
            break;
    }

    return (test);
}

private state mstate = state.normal;

private enum state
{
    normal,
    pressed,
    hovered
}

public static bool PointInTriangle(PointF p, PointF p0, PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    float s = p0.Y * p2.X - p0.X * p2.Y + (p2.Y - p0.Y) * p.X + (p0.X - p2.X) * p.Y;
    float t = p0.X * p1.Y - p0.Y * p1.X + (p0.Y - p1.Y) * p.X + (p1.X - p0.X) * p.Y;
    if ((s < 0) != (t < 0))
        return false;
    float a = -p1.Y * p2.X + p0.Y * (p2.X - p1.X) + p0.X * (p1.Y - p2.Y) + p1.X * p2.Y;
    if (a < 0.0)
    {
        s = -s;
        t = -t;
        a = -a;
    }
    return s > 0 && t > 0 && (s + t) <= a;
}

protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    this.SetMeasuredDimension(this.MeasuredWidth, 3 * this.MeasuredWidth / 4);
}

public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
{
    int width = this.MeasuredWidth;
    switch (mstate)
    {
        case state.normal:
            Paint paintFill = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
            paintFill.StrokeWidth = 2;
            paintFill.Color = this.Hovered ? Color.Red : new Color(242, 180, 54);
            paintFill.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Fill);
            paintFill.AntiAlias = true;

            Paint paintStroke = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
            paintStroke.StrokeWidth = 2;
            paintStroke.Color = Color.White;
            paintStroke.SetStyle(Android.Graphics.Paint.Style.Stroke);
            paintStroke.AntiAlias = true;

            PointF point1Draw;
            PointF point2Draw;
            PointF point3Draw;
            if (this._direction == TriangularButtonDirection.Up)
            {
                point1Draw = new PointF(0, 3f * width / 4);
                point2Draw = new PointF(width, 3f * width / 4);
                point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                point1Draw = new PointF(0, 0);
                point2Draw = new PointF(width, 0);
                point3Draw = new PointF(width / 2f, 3f * width / 4);
            }

            Path path = new Path();
            path.SetFillType(Path.FillType.EvenOdd);
            path.MoveTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
            path.LineTo(point2Draw.X, point2Draw.Y);
            path.LineTo(point3Draw.X, point3Draw.Y);
            path.LineTo(point1Draw.X, point1Draw.Y);
            path.Close();

            canvas.DrawPath(path, paintFill);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paintStroke);
            break;

        case state.hovered:
            //TODO:
            break;

        case state.pressed:
            //TODO:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, I already try that but cannot get the three sides stroked, and when you click outside the triangle the click still raised.

Comment: @Geotinc, for three-sides-stroke issue, I updated my answer, you can have a check. For the problem that "when you click outside the triangle the click still raised.", yes, cause the default button is a rectangle. Working on this.

Comment: @Geotinc, oh, I do see your code that for calculating the react region for clicking, I think you can recalculate it and use your `TriangularButton` with selector for background together.

Comment: @Geotinc, I continued to work with your code, just tested the code for clicking, it works, for hover state, I'm not sure it's right. You can have a test with my update 2 version. If still have problem, you can leave a comment. I will come back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works but there is a bug. When you touch the button move your finger outside the button and release it the button is still in pressed state (e.Action is equal to Moove)

Comment: @Geotinc, my thought was right, it's the return value issue, sometimes your "test" get to false when the button is pressed. Then the `up` event will not be fired. To solve this issue, add this code `test = true;` in the `case MotionEventActions.Down:`. I just tested hundred times, seems works fine now. You may have a try.